# SBT Eclipse not generating projects for aggregating sub-projects

Tags: sbt, sbteclipse

Assume a hierarchical project layout as the following:

```
root
 -subproject1
 -subproject2
```

where root only aggregates all subprojects.

Calling `eclipse` in root, as expected, generates importable eclipse projects for all subprojects.

However, now consider that subproject 1 also aggregates subproject 2. Calling the `eclipse` task in either root or subproject 1 generates project files for all but subproject 1. In summary, having an "aggregation graph" such as

```
      -> subproject1
    /        |
root         |
    \        v
      -> subproject2
```

never generates eclipse files for subproject 1.

Am I missing something about aggregation semantics or is this a bug in sbteclipse?

A concrete case where this problem occurs can be found in the build file [here](https://github.com/jodersky/vfd/blob/402d5c80d54f16d41a4544131a7c09ff26f7aa84/project/Build.scala). Project "vfd-main" never has any eclipse projects generated unless removing its own aggregation settings on line 58.
Btw, I am using sbteclipse version 3.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is the expected behavior. Since subproject1 aggregates other projects, it is considered a parent and, by default, no project definitions are generated for parents. This can be changed by adding

```
EclipseKeys.skipParents in ThisBuild := false
```

to the build.